# can't get highlight.js to highlight React rendered code

Tags: reactjs, markdown, syntax-highlighting, highlight.js

Here's my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MarkdownRenderer from 'react-markdown-renderer';

export default class Content extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      content: ''
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    let file_path = this.props.mdfPath;
    fetch(file_path)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(content => {
        this.setState({ content })
      })
    }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <MarkdownRenderer markdown={this.state.content}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This component fetches the content of any markdown file whose path is passed to it (through props), and then makes use of [`react-markdown-renderer`](https://github.com/InsidersByte/react-markdown-renderer) to turn that markdown into HTML.

I've downloaded the `hihglight.js` files and pointed to them in my index.html file. I also have run, inside index.html, the function `initHighlightingOnLoad()`. However, **when the site loads, my code block isn't highlighted**. I'm not sure what's going on... Can someone help please?

This is what `<MarkdownRenderer markdown={this.state.content} />` outputs to the DOM

```
<div>
  <h1>My Site</h1>
  <p>This is my site...</p>
  <pre>
    <code class="language-js">
      const msg = 'Welcome to My Site';
      console.log(msg); // Welcome to My SIte
    </code>
  </pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

For everyone who didn't find any working answer above and have no success with `initHighlightingOnLoad` and others builtin functions.

React: 16.8.2 working example:

```
import hljs from "highlight.js";
import "./dracula.css";

class Preview extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateCodeSyntaxHighlighting();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.updateCodeSyntaxHighlighting();
  }

  updateCodeSyntaxHighlighting = () => {
    document.querySelectorAll("pre code").forEach(block => {
      hljs.highlightBlock(block);
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
    <div
        className="content"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.parsedText }}
    />
    );
  }
}
```

Note that `updateCodeSyntaxHighlighting` should be in `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` methods in every component which use `<pre><code>...` tags.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that your React app hasn't initialized the component yet at the time when the index.html runs `initHighlightingOnLoad()`

Try moving `initHighlightingOnLoad()` inside `componentDidMount` of your `Content` component

Comment: I tried doing that but nothing still :( I did read something in [this thread][1] that suggests your guess is right. I tried what was suggested there too without success...

[1]: https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js/issues/925

Answer (score 1):

@pkuzhel's answered worked for me, I had the same problem. Hope this can help

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import hljs from 'highlight.js';
import 'highlight.js/styles/vs2015.css';

hljs.configure({useBR: true});

export default class Post extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>       
                <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.text }}></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks at the 'code' block in a HTML string

Highlight.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import hljs from "highlight.js";
import 'highlight.js/styles/vs2015.css';

class Highlight extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.updateCodeSyntaxHighlighting();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.updateCodeSyntaxHighlighting();
    }


    updateCodeSyntaxHighlighting = () => {
        document.querySelectorAll("code").forEach(block => {
            hljs.highlightBlock(block);
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", overflow: "auto", objectFit: "cover" }}
                className="content"
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.body }}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default Highlight;
```

To use it

```
import Highlight from "../path/to/Highlight"
< Highlight body={HTML_STRING} />
```